# How do I use a Get query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, fetch-api

Hello I created a form allowing me to choose which database table I want to observe. I then want to make a query based on the selected data but it seems that the format or my way of doing it does not seem good.

Here is my fetch function:

```
temp_select: 'temperature'

async exportData(){
const data_select = encodeURIComponent(this.temp_select);
const url = `http://192.168.1.51:3000/api/v1/export/${data_select}`;
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(typeof(data_select));
            const data = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });

},
```

and here is my query function

```
async function exportDatabase(req, res){
const data_selected = req.params.data_select;
return db.any('SELECT $1 FROM tag_7z8eq73', [data_selected])
    .then(rows => {
        res.json(rows)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

}

the database is loaded but here is what I observe

[image]

It works correctly in this form:

```
async function exportDatabase(req, res){
return db.any('SELECT temperature FROM tag_7z8eq73')
    .then(rows => {
        res.json(rows)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    }); }
```

[image]

I'm working with node.js and vue.js

Can someone enlighten me?

**edit** : @Quentin Thank you for your answer you help me understand how the GET request works. Here is my problem solved :

fetch function :

```
async exportData(){
const data_select = encodeURIComponent(this.temp_select);
const url = `http://192.168.1.51:3000/api/v1/export/${data_select}`;
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(typeof(data_select));
            const data = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });

},
```

Query function:

```
async function exportDatabase(req, res){
const data_selected = req.params.data_select;
return db.any('SELECT ' + data_selected + ' FROM tag_7z8eq73')
    .then(rows => {
        res.json(rows)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    }); }
```

my route :

```
router.get('/export/:data_select', db.exportDatabase);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> method: 'GET',
> ```

You are making a GET request

---

> ```
> headers: {
>     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
> },
> ```

This claims that the request body is JSON.

GET requests cannot have a request body, so this cannot be true.

(Technically they can, but really shouldn't, but `fetch` won't let you give a GET request a body).

Remove this header.

---

> ```
> params: JSON.stringify({
>     data_select: this.temp_select,          
> }),
> ```

`fetch` does not have a `params` option, so this is nonsense. Remove it.

---

> ```
> async function exportDatabase(req, res){
>      return db.any('SELECT $1 FROM tag_7z8eq73', [req.params.data_select])
> ```

Assuming you are using Express, look at [the definition of `params`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params):

> This property is an object containing properties mapped to the named route “parameters”. For example, if you have the route /user/:name, then the “name” property is available as req.params.name. This object defaults to {}.

Which means you need to define `data_select` when you define the route:

```
app.get('/api/v1/export/:data_select', exportData);
```

And then put the value **in the URL** when you make the request:

```
const data_select = encodeURIComponent(this.temp_select);
const url = `http://192.168.1.51:3000/api/v1/export/${data_select}`;
fetch(url).then(...);
```

Comment: Thank you sir I understand better how the GET request works. I have edited my question and made the changes =)